# Word to describe "A single point of entry"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

If there is not such a single word, the a shorter phrase or more eloquent way to sat it would do.

Comment: To give us context, please update your question with an example.

Comment: 'The only way in' is more concise, more idiomatic, but less eloquent.

Comment: Please take that Question somewhere like English Language Learners…

Answer (score 1):

"The only entrance" is shorter.

Comment: Please add sources to support your answer.

Comment: @JJJ Does this really needs a source? Seems clear an succinct.

Comment: Indeed it seems pretty obvious, it was in the low-quality queue and it's good practise to add sources to support your answers with sources or at least an example of its use. In this case I agree that your answer is pretty clear, but other community members might disagree and vote down or even vote to delete your answer.

Comment: It doesn't need a supporting reference. It needs deleting as unsuitable on a site aimed at linguists.